# Information about upgrading a Resharper plugin to v 5.0

Tags: resharper, upgrade, resharper-5.0

I like the sound of the [Exceptional plugin](http://exceptionalplugin.codeplex.com/) for resharper, but it says it currently only works with v4.5.  Does anyone know what is involved with upgrading to 5.0 and how much things have changed, which bits will need to be looked at etc.  I am quite tempted to upgrade it but would like some pointers before I start...

Answer (score 0):

There's no documentation as such, but please feel free to ping me and I can try and help.

Comment: It would be much better if you would put all this contact information on your profile page. If most of the post is a generic signature with only remotely related links, it looks more like spam than like an answer. Also there already is your icon with your name at the bottom of each of your posts, so an additional signature is not adding anything.